# How do you OR two LIKE statements?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have tried the following two statements:

- `SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE col (LIKE 'str1' OR LIKE 'str2') AND col2 = num` results in a syntax error
- `SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE page LIKE ('str1' OR 'str2') AND col2 = num` results in "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: str1" and "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: str2" for what looks like every result. However, no results are actually returned.

I figured one of the two statements would work, but they aren't.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE (col LIKE 'str1' OR col LIKE 'str2') AND col2 = num
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need `WHERE ((page LIKE 'str1') OR (page LIKE 'str2'))`

Answer (score 5):

USE `%` at the Start and End of the String. So that it will check the Sub-Strings as well

```
SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE (col LIKE '%str1%' OR col LIKE '%str2%') AND col2 = num
```

Answer (score 3):

The "OR" operator applies to expressions.  "LIKE 'str1'" and "LIKE 'str2'" are not valid expressions, since the "LIKE" operator requires both a left hand side and a right hand side.

```
page LIKE ('str1' OR 'str2')
```

would first try to OR together 'str1' and 'str2', giving the value TRUE.  It would then try and evaluate `page LIKE TRUE`, and report an error.

Comment: This only shows what went wrong. This is not an answer though!

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you want is,

```
SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE col LIKE '%str[12]%' AND col2 = num
```

That will literally find all cases where (col like %str1% or col like %str2%) AND col2 = num

Comment: That does not work in MySQL as MySQL only has two wildcards, i.e. `%` and `_`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE (col LIKE 'str1' or col LIKE 'str2') AND col2 = num
```

Answer (score 2):

Think simple:

```
SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE (col LIKE 'str1' OR col LIKE 'str2') AND col2 = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of SQL you can use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT col FROM db.tbl WHERE col IN('str1','str2') AND col2 = num
```