# How to make all combinations with given words in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-operator

I'll make a search query that search on each individual word contains in my table using SQL Server. The query must work as following situation:

1. The query must search in the `colour`, `style`, `marerial` and `shape` field like an *or* operator
2. The query must search on each individual search word (like `blue`, `red`, `modern` and `wood`) with all possible combinations between this words.
3. The search values must contain in a column like an *like* operator.

This means for this words that I only can find the products with [[`colour like '%blue%'` or `colour like '%red%'`], `material like '%wood%'`, `style like '%modern%'` and each shape]. *(required output)* in other words all the combinations with each word.

Here is my query so far:

```sql
select distinct colour, style, material, shape
from products
where colour in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') or
      style in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') or
      material in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') or
      shape in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') ;
```

This is the result:

| colour | style | material | shape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Modern | Aluminum | Round |  |
| Modern | Metal | Round |  |
| Albast | Modern | Acrylic | Round |
| Albast | Modern | Glass | Cylinder |
| Albast | Modern | Glass | Other |
| Albast | Modern | Glass | Rectangle |
| Albast | Modern | Glass | Round |
| Albast | Modern | Glass | Square |
| Albast | Modern | Synthetic Material | Globe |
| Albast | Modern | Synthetic Material | Round |
| Amber | Modern | Steel | Round |
| Black | Cottage | Wood |  |
| Black | Cottage | Wood | Round |
| Black | Modern | Reflector |  |
| Black | Modern | Abs | Round |
| Black | Modern | Acrylic | Round |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum |  |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Corner-Shaped |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Cylinder |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Half-Round |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Other |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Oval |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Rectangle |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Round |
| Black | Modern | Aluminum | Square |
| Black | Modern | Cotton | Hexagon |
| Black | Modern | Cotton | Round |
| Black | Modern | Glass | Rectangle |

But I see that the result is bases on one or many word could be find or not.

I've also tried this query but found no results.

```sql
select distinct colour, style, material, shape
from products
where colour in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') and
      style in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') and
      material in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') and
      shape in ('blue', 'red', 'modern', 'wood') ;
```

I'm not able to find if a word is a colour, shape, style or material.

Update: Expected result

| colour | style | material | shape |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | modern style | wood | round |
| red | modern | wood | Rectangle |
| red | modern | wood | round |
| blue | modern | wood | Rectangle |
| blue | modern | wood | globe |
| red | modern | wood | globe |

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Is that output what you want, or are you trying to generate something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Stands in my question. I've updated it so it's clear

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn Even with the updated explanation I don't understand what you are looking for and what is wrong with your current query.

Comment: maybe so?? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240582/how-do-you-or-two-like-statements>

Comment: I guess here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865353/combining-like-and-in-for-sql-server

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I've added a table with the expected result

Comment: That's a really bad way to ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I've found this solution:

- I've created a stored procedure whit one parameter: `@query`.
- Then I split my query on spaces. See the accepted answer from this question: [Splitting the string in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428612/splitting-the-string-in-sql-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).
- Then I made my select statement.
- And for every part of my query I add my where clause and replace `{0}` with my query part.
- Then just add `1 = 1` to got a valid SQL query.
- Execute my generated SQL query using `EXEC` statement.
- Last execute my stored procedure.

Here is my code:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @q nvarchar(max);
declare @whereClause nvarchar(max);
declare @currentrow int = 1;

declare @totalqueries int = (select count(pn) 
                             from dbo.SplitString(' ', @query)); -- count how many query 
                                                                 -- parts I've got.

set @sql = 'select distinct colour, style, material, shape
            from products 
            where '; -- my select statement

set @whereClause = 'colour + style + material + shape like ''%{0}%'' and '; -- where clause

while @currentrow <= @totalqueries begin;

    select @q = s 
    from dbo.SplitString(' ', @query)
    where pn = @currentrow;

    set @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@whereClause, '{0}', @q); -- replacing `{0}` with my 
                                                        -- query part `@q`

    set @currentrow = @currentrow + 1;

end;

set @sql = @sql + ' 1 = 1;';

exec (@sql);
```

See also this function:

```
create FUNCTION dbo.SplitString (@sep nvarchar(1), @s varchar(4000))
    RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
        FROM Pieces
        WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
        SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no clean solution. This statement could do the job:

```
select distinct colour, style, material, shape
from products 
where colour + style + material + shape like '%blue%' or
      colour + style + material + shape like '%red%' or
      colour + style + material + shape like '%modern%' or
      colour + style + material + shape like '%wood%';
```

Comment: Not really what I need, it's looks like an translation of the `in`-operator. But +1 for the idea